# GNU Grub / Windows Bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, kali

I had a multiboot system, with Ubuntu in partition `/dev/sda7`, Windows in `/dev/sda2` and Kali in `/dev/sda5`.

Before i install Ubuntu Gnome, I used the bootloader Windows to chose the OS that I want, but now after the installation of Ubuntu,when I start my machine, I have grub and if I select windows loader, I have the bootloader of windows

I would like remove grub, because I had already configured the Windows bootloader to boot Kali/Windows 10/Ubuntu.

I tried to search how to uninstall grub, but i'm scared about not being able to reboot my machine after that...

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot Windows 10 and install EasyBCD
2. Open EasyBCD and click on "BCD Deployement"
3. In the section "MBR Configuration Options" ensure that "Install the Windows Vista/7 bootloader to the MBR" is selected and click the "Write MBR" button
4. Reboot
5. If necessary, add Linux entries in EasyBCD