# GRUB4DOS 0.4.5b 2011-11-27

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

My problem arrived after this solution : [GNU Grub / Windows Bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889486/gnu-grub-windows-bootloader)
I used the fonction "EasyBCD->BCD Deployement->Write MBR"
After that, my problem was fix, but after the reboot, the program EasyBCD 2.3 refuse to launch, i uninstall it, reinstall, remove the folder and try again, but the program won't work...
So I install an old version ( 2.1.2 ) in order to add a new entry in MBR to launch Ubuntu... I select "Add New ENtry->Linux/BSD->Grub2"

I rebooted my machine and i selected the option grub 2... But after that my machine show "

```
GRUB4DOS 0.4.5b 2011-11-27
[Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename.]
grub>
```

So i tried to do some command in this panel, but it say that i must load the kernel first, but the command linux `/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda6` give to me an error...

Thanks for all ^^

Comment: Is this older system using BIOS/MBR. Newer systems use UEFI/gpt and do not need EasyBCD. We also do not recommend EasyBCD as it forces you to install Ubuntu's grub2 to a partition. That forces it to use blocklists which are unreliable. Better to just use grub2 to dual boot.  If you really want BCD you may do better here: http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use boot-repair-disk to reinstall grub. It is live bootable cd, Before repairing boot loader, must connect to WiFi network.

Comment: Boot-repair has change nothing

Comment: You have, changed manually, many settings of grub, according to to me only super grub 2 disk can help you.  It is only about 25 mb .